# Filtering API results in python and storing them in a variable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to filter the results of an API that fetches the price of cryptocurrencies and stores them in a variable.

As the API returns a lot of information, and I don't know how to filter the API result down to the bit I want to save as a variable. I can see it's a dictionary inside a list.

An example of part of what the API returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "9664.78089392", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "23448292797.3", 
        "market_cap_usd": "172238350864", 
        "available_supply": "17821237.0", 
        "total_supply": "17821237.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-3.71", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-9.29", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-22.53", 
        "last_updated": "1563299071", 
        "price_gbp": "7789.77474138", 
        "24h_volume_gbp": "18899230201.5", 
        "market_cap_gbp": "138823421843"
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:
I'm trying to get the value of "price_gbp" and store it in a variable, let's call it 'btc_price_gbp'
Sorry, I'm very, very tired.

Comment: loop through the list, and access each value by the key?

Comment: You forgot to state what you  are actually trying to do.... For example, what is the expected output here?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python access list" and [Python access dict", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the content you're receiving from the API isn't exactly a list, but a JSON.

This is how you can reach the value of "price_gbp":

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=GBP'
print(requests.get(url).json()[0]["price_gbp"])
```

Comment: There are lots of values in the API under the value of "price_gbp", you can see here: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=GBP  So this isn't working, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joshe\Desktop\tests.py", line 7, in <module>
    load = json.loads(result)
  File "C:\Users\joshe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Response

Comment: Are you using 'requests'? I gonna update the code above assuming that.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has got it working! I cannot thank you enough seriously i’ve been trying to do this all week, you are a hero!